# Ubuntu Vserver (Strato): wsgi script is shown as plain text

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I have tested the configuration on a local Gentoo box, but on my Strato-vServer it does not work:

```
$ apache2 -M|grep wsgi
wsgi_module (shared)
```

---

```
# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default 
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/default/

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/default/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

    SetHandler wsgi-script
    Options ExecCGI

    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/vhosts/default/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/default/cgi-bin/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The wsgi script:

```
root@h1900160:/var/www/vhosts/default/cgi-bin# cat test.wsgi 
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = "200 OK"
    output = "Hello World!"

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

The script is only shown as plain text.
Error log says this:

```
[Fri May 13 12:54:02 2011] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14311): Attach interpreter ''.
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that it will solve your problem, but you should have the line:

```
SetHandler wsgi-script
```

The line:

```
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
```

already ensures that anything with .wsgi extension is process by mod_wsgi. Adding SetHandler will only serve to cause you .cgi scripts to no longer be served as CGI scripts. Also, you wouldn't be able to server up static files any more either.